# Retrieving COM class factory ... failed error 80040154

Tags: dll, components

I have an old VB.Net application using Interop.ebCryptLib.dll that I couldn't get to work. I get the following error:

```
Retrieving COM class factory for component with CLSID {...} failed due to the following error: 80040154
```

I've searched for the error online and tried the following:

1. Register the dll using regsvr32 but I get the error "entry point was not found"
2. I tried recompiling the project and set the platform to x86 but still get the same error.

Is there any other suggestion I can try? This is an old application developed by another person. I do have access to the code and am unable to get it to work properly.

Comment: You have to register the original component, not the Interop library that was created for it.  Contact the owner of the component for assistance for proper install instructions.

Comment: @Hans I have the original project file for this VB.Net application. Is there anyway I can recompile it to fix it without having to look for the original component?

Comment: Did you at least try?  No, that project file isn't going to help you get the COM component you need.

Comment: @HansPassant, I'm not sure where to find the owner for that component. I couldn't find it online and I don't know the original programmer of the application.

Comment: Obviously you are not going to find him here.  Talk to people inside your company.  If everybody quit their job then, well, that would be a good idea too.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Was able to resolve this by finding the original ebCrypt.dll online. Thanks for the help @HansPassant